# LibGDX fbx-conv from Blender not passing specular color to G3DJ

Tags: libgdx, fbx

I have a model in blender 2.8 with a specular value of 0 using the Pricipled BSDF node. I export as an fbx file and then convert it using fbx-conv (https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv). When looking at the g3dj file, the material always has a specular color of .800000. I'm using the latest fbx-conv

[Blender Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyeMe.png)

fbx-conv inacurate [G3DJ results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THsjQ.png)

In Blender 2.76 I was able to set the specular color of a model, and after running the fbx-conv, it would have an appropriate specular color in the G3DJ file.

[Blender 2.76 setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2MMV.png) (note specular color is black)

[G3DJ results from blender 2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mE9H.png)

I'm guessing I'm setting something up incorrectly in Blender 2.8 or the fbx-conv needs to be updated. I'd really appreciate any help with why the specular value is not being converted correctly.

*Note - After playing around with Blender 2.8 a bit more I discovered that by setting the base color before setting the texture will set the diffuse and specular color in the g3dj file (even though applying a texture looks like it overwrites the color). I'm still trying to figure it out, but I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I highly recommend using the gdx-gltf library for exporting and loading models. It’s less finicky than having to use fbx-conv and is still actively developed unlike libGDX’s 3D api. https://github.com/mgsx-dev/gdx-gltf

Comment: Thanks TenFour04! That would solve my problem.